# Why is the priemage of a regular value of $F(x,v)=df_x(v)$ finite?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

This comes up as part of a larger issue of showing a compact $n$-dimensional manifold can be immersed in $\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$ except at finitely many points.

Suppose $X$ is a compact, $n$-dimensional manifold. Let $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ be an immersion. Say you have a map $F\colon T(X)\to\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ given by $F(x,v)=df_x(v)$, with a regular value $a$. I'm interested in why the preimage $F^{-1}(a)$ is necessarily finite. After this, I think I have an idea to show $X$ can be immersed into $\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$ except on $F^{-1}(a)$.

So I think it suffices to show that $a$ has only finitely many preimages in $\{(x,v):|v|\leq 1\}$ in the tangent bundle $T(X)$. Towards the contrary, suppose there are infinitely many preimages $(x_i,v_i)$. By compactness, there is a convergent sequence such that $x_i\to x$ and $v_i/|v_i|\to w$. Apparently this implies $df_x(w)=0$, but how does this give a contradiction?

By linearity, I find the equation
$$
F(x_i,v_i/|v_i|)=df_{x_i}(v_i/|v_i|)=a/|v_i|
$$
Is the idea that we can without loss of generality assume that $|v_i|\to\infty$, so as $i\to\infty$, $df_x(w)=0$? But why does that show $F^{-1}(a)$ is finite? Thank you.

Comment: what is the definition of f?

Comment: @XipanXiao Sorry, $f$ is just an immersion from $X\to\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Comment: Just note first that $F$ is proper, everything else is immediate.

Comment: Thanks @studiosus. Do you mind expanding your comment so I can accept an answer?

Answer (score 3):

First note that, since $f$ is an immersion, the map $F$ is (linear) injective and, hence, proper on each tangent space $T_xX$. Therefore, (by compactness if $X$) the map $F$ is proper, which means that preimage of a compact is compact. Now, you have a regular point $a\in {\mathbb R}^{2n}$ of $F$, meaning that for each $b\in F^{-1}(b)$ the derivative $DF_b$ is surjective. But $\dim TX= \dim {\mathbb R}^{2n}$, therefore, $DF_b$ is also injective. Thus, $F$ is a local diffeomorphism at each $b\in F^{-1}(a)$. Note that $F^{-1}(a)\subset TX$ is closed (actually, compact). If $F^{-1}(a)$ has an accumulation point $b$, we obtain a contradiction to the local injectivity of $F$ at each $b\in F^{-1}(a)$. Thus, $F^{-1}(a)$ is compact and discrete, hence, it is finite. qed

**Edit.** In order to prove properness of the map $F: TX\to {\mathbb R}^{2n}$:

Without loss of generality we may assume that $X$ is embedded in some ${\mathbb R}^N$ (maybe your book even defined differentiable manifolds this way). Suppose that $f: X\to {\mathbb R}^{2n}$ is an immersion, $x_i \in X$ is a sequence converging to some $x\in X$ and $v_i\in T_{x_i}X$ is a sequence of tangent vectors such that the norms
$$
df_{x_i}(v_i)
$$
are uniformly bounded. Then the norms of the vectors $v_i$ are also uniformly bounded. A hint for this exercise is to take a small neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f|_U$ is an embedding and think about the derivative of the inverse map
$$
f^{-1}: f(U)\to X. 
$$

Comment: That's my issue though. Where have I shown that the preimage of any point under $F$ is discrete?

Comment: @Chelsea: The map F is also an immersion over $a$ and, hence is locally injective. Thus, preimage of each point under F is discrete.

Comment: To ask a contrary question, let $f: M\to N$ be smooth map between $n$-dimensional compact manifolds, suppose each $p\in N$, the preimage $f^{-1}(p)$ is discrete, can we say $f$ is a local diffemorphism?

Comment: @YilongZhang: This would be false. Take for instance the map $f(x)=x^2$ from the real line to itself.

Comment: @studiosus Thanks for that example, but I mentioned that manifold should be compact. Maybe you want to say $f(x)=x^2$ with restriction to $x\in [-1,1]$, but it's manifold with boundary. So we can ask about if the claim true for compact manifold without boundary.

Comment: @studiosus Here is an counter-example: consider $f: S^1\to S^1$ be smooth map, which is homotopic to constant map, then $df$ vanishes at the point which the loop "turn back".

Comment: @YilongZhang: Extend the map $x\to x^2$ to the 1-point compactification of the real line (know as the circle or $RP^1$), where I use the chart $z\to z^{-1}$ at infinity. This map is smooth  and has two critical points $0, \infty$. In any case, if you want to ask a question, ask it in a separate MSE question instead of a comment.

Comment: @studiosus That's a good point, thanks for that, and also thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I’m stuck with this problem also. Can you show me how F is proper with more detail? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @N.Quy: Note that $X$ is compact, $f$ is continuous, hence, preimages of compact sets are closed, hence, compact (closed subsets of compacts are compact).

Comment: @MoisheKohan, I knew that fact, but here is the $F$, the preimage $F^{-1}(a)$ is a subset of $T(X)$, which I do not know is compact or not. As your answer, I do not understand clearly the point "since $f$ is an immersion, the map $F$ is (linear) injective and, hence, proper on each tangent space $T_x(X)$.

Comment: @N.Quy: See the edit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your edit.